# How can I insert a character in a string?

Tags: bash, sed

I have tried

```
echo "ABCDE-123456" | sed 's/-//' | sed 's/./& -/g'
A -B -C -D -E -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -
```

sed is not putting the **-** on the first character.
How can I make it output

`-A -B -C -D -E -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6`
`

Comment: what about `sed 's/./-& /g'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn around your `sed` replacement string to be `-&`.

Also, no need to call `sed` twice as you can combine multiple commands with `;`.

```
sed 's/-//; s/./-& /g'
```

Note, that you will have a space at the end which you might need to get rid of.